# Getting same record from different skips

Tags: mongodb

I'm sorting items by status, and with multiple different skips I'm getting same record.

I used aggregation framework.

1st query:

```
db.order.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "orderId": "$order_id",
      "name": 1,
      "dateCreated": "$date_created",
      "status": 1,
      "dueDate": "$deliveryMethod.delivery_date",
      "selectedQuantity": {
        "$sum": "$items.selectedQuantity"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "status": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 16
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

2nd query:

```
db.order.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "orderId": "$order_id",
      "name": 1,
      "dateCreated": "$date_created",
      "status": 1,
      "dueDate": "$deliveryMethod.delivery_date",
      "selectedQuantity": {
        "$sum": "$items.selectedQuantity"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "status": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 17
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

I expected different record to get since in second query record with name 15 should be skipped.

[first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhYD8.jpg)
[second query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXojp.jpg)

Comment: Couldn't find anything wrong in the query.
May be you have some duplicate data and because of that it seems like the same result. 
Tried with skip 1 and 2 here https://mongoplayground.net/p/mhJdRxf1GwP and I get the different result.

Comment: If you are sorting results by `status` and multiple results have the same `status`, the sort order is  not guaranteed. Technically any ordering of documents with the same `status` would satisfy the requested sort order. If you want a predictable sort order you should choose a unique sort key. For example, assuming `orderId` is  a unique field: `{ status: -1, orderId: 1}`,

Comment: @Stennie I thought the same thing, but it's strange that when I run 1st query then 2nd then 1st again, it always gives me same result. If the sort isn't guaranteed I expected to get every time different result.

Comment: If you are using a non-deterministic sort order I expect the order wouldn't be different every time ... but it may not always be the same. Even if your two queries observationally appear to have the expected outcome, updates to documents and indexes may lead to documents having a different natural order (aka "the order they are found"). The server is only guaranteeing that the results match the overall requested sort order, so if you require a predictable outcome you need to use a more granular sort key.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @razzil1 problem is => your sort is not working because your projection.

After your projection where you said "status" : 1 => mongodb doesn't know to 
sort "$sort" : { "status" : -1} because he doesn't recognize, you need to put "status" : "$status"

Regards,
Salesh